# SQL Condition on Window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to do a special request on my database (PostgreSQL v9.4.5), but I don't manage to do it.

In order to simply, let's say I have the following table **AvgTemperatures**, representing different averages of temperature taken in different cities, and calculated on different length of time (counted in months) :

```
 id |   city    |  avg | months 
----+-----------+------+--------
  1 |  New-York |   20 |     3   <--- average temperate over the last 3 months
  2 |  New-York |   19 |     6   <--- average temperate over the last 6 months
  3 |  New-York |   15 |    12   <--- etc
  4 |  New-York |   15 |    24
  5 |    Boston |   13 |     3
  6 |    Boston |   18 |     8
  7 |    Boston |   17 |    12
  8 |    Boston |   16 |    15
  9 |   Chicago |   12 |     2
 10 |   Chicago |   14 |    12
 11 |     Miami |   28 |     1
 12 |     Miami |   25 |     4
 13 |     Miami |   21 |    12
 14 |     Miami |   22 |    15
 15 |     Miami |   20 |    24
```

Now, imagine that I want to select all the rows concerning the measures in a city where at least one average has been over 19 degrees. In this case I want :

```
 id |   city    |  avg | months 
----+-----------+------+--------
  1 |  New-York |   20 |     3  
  2 |  New-York |   19 |     6  
  3 |  New-York |   15 |    12  
  4 |  New-York |   15 |    24  
 11 |     Miami |   28 |     1  
 12 |     Miami |   25 |     4  
 13 |     Miami |   21 |    12  
 14 |     Miami |   22 |    15  
 15 |     Miami |   20 |    24
```

I could do something like :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM AvgTemperatures
 WHERE MIN(avg) OVER (PARTITION BY city) > 16
```

But :

```
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: window functions not allowed in WHERE clause
```

What's more, I cannot use `GROUP BY` as in :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM AvtTemperatures
 GROUP BY city
 HAVING MIN(avg) > 16
```

because I will lose information due to the aggregation (by the way this query is not valid because of the "SELECT *").

I'm pretty sure I can use the `OVER PARTITION BY` to solve that, but I don't know how. Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[All-at-once operation:](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx#All-at-Once)**

> "All-at-Once Operations" means that all expressions in the same
> logical query process phase are evaluated logically at the same time.

And great chapter **Impact on Window Functions**:

Suppose you have:

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( Id INT) ;
 
INSERT  INTO Test VALUES  ( 1001 ), ( 1002 ) ;

SELECT Id
FROM Test
WHERE Id = 1002
  AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) = 1;
```

> **All-at-Once operations tell us these two conditions evaluated logically at the same point of time.** Therefore, SQL Server can
> evaluate conditions in WHERE clause in arbitrary order, based on
> estimated execution plan. So the main question here is which condition
> evaluates first.

**Case 1:**

`If ( Id = 1002 ) is first, then if ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) = 1 )`

Result: 1002

**Case 2:**

`If ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) = 1 ), then check if ( Id = 1002 )`

Result: empty

> **So we have a paradox.**

> This example shows why we cannot use Window Functions in WHERE clause.
> You can think more about this and find why Window Functions are
> allowed to be used just in **SELECT** and **ORDER BY** clauses!

To get what you want you can wrap windowed function with `CTE/subquery` as in [Gordon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629600/5070879):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT t.*, MAX(AVG) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS average
  FROM avgTemperatures t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
where average > 19
ORDER BY id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e700e8854f617482e779e13478c75776)**

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦═════╦═════════╗
║ id  ║   city   ║ avg ║ months  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════╬═════════╣
║   1 ║ New-York ║  20 ║     3   ║
║   2 ║ New-York ║  19 ║     6   ║
║   3 ║ New-York ║  15 ║    12   ║
║   4 ║ New-York ║  15 ║    24   ║
║  11 ║ Miami    ║  28 ║     1   ║
║  12 ║ Miami    ║  25 ║     4   ║
║  13 ║ Miami    ║  21 ║    12   ║
║  14 ║ Miami    ║  22 ║    15   ║
║  15 ║ Miami    ║  20 ║    24   ║
╚═════╩══════════╩═════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well it is for SQL Server example but explain why you can't use Windowed function in `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use the [`bool_or` aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select id, city, avg, months
from avttemperatures
where city in (
    select city
    from avttemperatures
    group by 1
    having bool_or(avg > 19)
)
order by  2, 4
;
 id |   city   | avg | months 
----+----------+-----+--------
 11 | Miami    |  28 |      1
 12 | Miami    |  25 |      4
 13 | Miami    |  21 |     12
 14 | Miami    |  22 |     15
 15 | Miami    |  20 |     24
  1 | New-York |  20 |      3
  2 | New-York |  19 |      6
  3 | New-York |  15 |     12
  4 | New-York |  15 |     24
```

The test table:

```
create table avttemperatures (
    id int, city text, avg int, months int
);
insert into avttemperatures (id, city, avg, months) values
(  1,'New-York',20,3),
(  2,'New-York',19,6),
(  3,'New-York',15,12),
(  4,'New-York',15,24),
(  5,'Boston',13,3),
(  6,'Boston',18,8),
(  7,'Boston',17,12),
(  8,'Boston',16,15),
(  9,'Chicago',12,2),
( 10,'Chicago',14,12),
( 11,'Miami',28,1),
( 12,'Miami',25,4),
( 13,'Miami',21,12),
( 14,'Miami',22,15),
( 15,'Miami',20,24);
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to aggregate if you only want to know if *at least one* exists:

```
SELECT id, city, avg, months
FROM avgtemperatures t
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 42
    FROM avgtemperatures x
    WHERE x.city = t.city
    AND x.avg > 19
    )
ORDER BY city,months DESC
   ;
```

Note: `avg` is a bad name for a column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap this in a derived table to be able to use in the where clause:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT t.*, MIN(avg) OVER (PARTITION BY city) as city_avg
  FROM AvgTemperatures t
) x
WHERE city_avg > 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get the maximum and then a `where`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(avg) over (partition by city) as maxavg
      from avgTemperatures t
     ) t
where maxavg > 19;
```

An alternative is to do this in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from avgTemperatures t
where t.city in (select t2.city from avgTemperatures t2 where t2.avg > 19);
```