# SQL Select calculation in where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a select statement and for one of the returned values I use a calculation.

What I would like to do is use the result of the calculation in the where clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY val1 ORDER BY val2) AS rnum,
val3,
FROM TestDb 
Where (rnum = 1)
```

But it does not like `rnum` being in the `where`.

I was thinking about creating a table and adding to that. Then I would be able to `select where rnum ...` but this doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: SELECT * FROM(your query here) WHERE rnum=1 or using a CTE are the most used solutions

Comment: Can you please post the schema and also the desired result you are seeking?

Comment: Thanks Mihai - that worked perfect :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select * from (
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY val1 ORDER BY val2) AS rnum, val3
FROM TestDb )TestDb 
Where (rnum = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use derived table (subquery/cte):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY val1 ORDER BY val2) AS rnum,
         val3
  FROM TestDb
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnum = 1;
```

If you wonder why you cannot use it directly please read [SQL Condition on Window function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629560/5070879)

Comment: You need to remove the Comma after val3