# Why is the Row_number function is generatign an error when using Where = 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the Row_Number and order by function to sort to a data set. I want to know the values where N = 2.
The query runs fine with I do not use 'where N = 2'. But when I add 'where N =2' then I get error. How do I get around this issue?

> Msg 207 Level 16 State 1 Line 15 Invalid column name 'N'

Sample of the code below

```
create table temp 
(
    col1 nvarchar(25), 
    col2 nvarchar(25)
)

insert into  temp
values ('Babahoyo', 'Ecuador'),
       ('Stavanger', 'Norway'),
       ('Seattle', 'USA'),
       ('New York City', 'USA')

select 
    row_number() over (order by col2) as N, 
    col1, col2
from
    temp
where 
    N = 2
```

[db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fccbbf8f6a31d0329bb1127a3691414b)

Comment: [SQL Condition on Window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629548/sql-condition-on-window-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Condition on Window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629548/sql-condition-on-window-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put `an alias reference` in `where clause`

```
select * from
(
select row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col2) as N, col1, col2
from temp
)A
where n = 2
```

Comment: @user716255, you can try the answer that I've given - using a subquery

Comment: More precisely and vaguely, you can't use a _column_ alias reference from the same "scope" in a `where` clause. A _table_ alias is different and, as shown in the code, a column alias from a nested scope, whether a subquery or CTE, is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select t.*
from temp
order by col2
offset 1 row fetch 1 row only
```